# How check asp.net 4 mvc2 site security?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

How check site security on asp.net4 mvc2?

I'm only 19 years old and I am very worried if I do not know what a vulnerability. I use **LINQ**, and it's mean, that **SQL Injection** - protected. **XSS** - I tried to use a special library *AntiXSS* (how check all on site to use it...?).

And of course all that I do not know.. Authorization (cookies, interception, etc.).
Sorry for my English. I would be very happy, if you can help me in this difficult and proud work - protection our sites.

*if necessary, I send the link to the site in PM*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of the most command exploits for web applications look at the [OWSAP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007) top 10. It gives information on the most serious exploits and how to protect against them.